# python selenium scrape item who contain partial text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract specific element from html table, this is my current code :

```
tabela  = soup.find("div", {"class" : "productDatatable"})
>>> tabela

<div class="productDatatable">\n<div>\r\n            Category:\r\n                        <span class="productDatatableValue">\n<a href="/en/market/mt5/utility">Utilities</a>\n</span>\n</div>\n<div title="Number of activations available for the buyers of this application. During the activation, software product is bound to the buyer's hardware, so that the copy of the application cannot work on another PC. The application should be re-activated and downloaded again in order to launch it on another computer. If the activation limit is exceeded, the buyer will have to purchase the product again.">\r\n            Activations:\r\n                        <span class="productDatatableValue">\r\n                            5\r\n                        </span>\n</div>\n<div style="padding:5px;"></div>\n<div>\r\n            Author:\r\n                        <span class="productDatatableValue">\n<span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;"><span class="icoVerified small" title="Verified User"></span></span>\n<span title="Konstantin Chernov"><a class="author" href="/en/users/konstantin83" title="Konstantin83">Konstantin Chernov</a></span>\n</span>\n</div>\n<div>\r\n            Published:\r\n                        <span class="productDatatableValue">\r\n                            16 January 2013\r\n                        </span>\n</div>\n<div>\r\n            Current version:\r\n                        <span class="productDatatableValue">1.55</span>\n</div>\n<div>\r\n            Updated:\r\n                        <span class="productDatatableValue">\r\n                            23 March 2015\r\n                        </span>\n</div>\n</div>
```

How i can extract category name from this html output.
i tried this, but not working.

```
tabela.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Category')]").find("span", {"class" : "productDatatable"}).text
```

How i can get category from this html ? i need output `Utilities`

Comment: please give your exact HTML of your tabela

Comment: @ManaliKagathara here is the full link https://www.mql5.com/en/market/product/635

Comment: here is my full python code : https://pastebin.com/raw/YrPzYdtX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Return `Utilities` which is there inside anchor tag not span.Try below Beautifulsoup code.
**EDITED:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
response=requests.get("https://www.mql5.com/en/market/product/635").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
tabela  = soup.find("div", class_="productDatatable").find('span', class_="productDatatableValue").find('a')
print(tabela.text)
```

---

**EDITED:**

If you want to use selenium use following xpath with reference of category

```
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'Category')]/span[@class='productDatatableValue']/a").text)
```

Comment: category is not all times `Utility` this is just example, category change

Comment: Based on your query I have posted the code.If you have any further requirements you need to post that.

Comment: @LucianBlaga : added xpath for selenium with reference to category.Hope this will help.

Comment: not working :( 
(Pdb) print(soup.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'Category')]/span[@class='productDatatableValue']/a").text)
*** TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @LucianBlaga : According to your code I have updated the BeautifulSoup code as well did you try that? With that given url beautifulsoup working fine.

Comment: @LucianBlaga : You have used wrong code for soup.Soup code is there in the first option please check. `print(soup.find("div", class_="productDatatable").find('span', class_="productDatatableValue").find('a').text)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one please

```
tabela.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/span/a").text
```

Comment: (Pdb) tabela.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='productDatatable']/div/span/a").text
*** TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @LucianBlaga try this one